# How to make more specific urlPattern override broader pattern with annotations

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, annotations

I currently have a main controller servlet with the following annotation:

```
@WebServlet(name="ControllerServlet", urlPatterns={"/", "/home"})
```

I have .js and .css files under the `/resources` dir in my project that my .jsp files reference and the links are getting sent to my main controller which I don't want. I made a second servlet to handle the .js .css files with nn annotation of:

```
@WevServlet(name="ResourceServlet", urlPatterns={"/resources"})
```

hoping that it would pick up the requests coming from my .jsp files but ControllerServlet is still picking them up. How can I make /resources urls get directed to my ResourceServlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url pattern `/` matches anything that isn't matched by the other mappings. If you have

```
@WebServlet(name="ResourceServlet", urlPatterns={"/resources"})
```

then a request to, eg. `localhost:8080/context/resources` will be handled by your `ResourceServlet`, but a request to `localhost:8080/context/resources/somescript.js` won't because it doesn't match `ResourceServlet`'s url pattern. Therefore, `ControllerServlet` will handle it.

You need to change your `ResourceServlet` mapping to

```
@WebServlet(name="ResourceServlet", urlPatterns={"/resources/*"})
```