# how to access static resources on Spring Security application using annotations?

Tags: java, static, spring-security, resources, annotations

I'm trying to access static content on a login page jsp and I'm failing to do so.

The security config method I'm using is:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**","/images/**")
        .access("hasRole('ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/user/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }
```

The login page that fails to load images and static resources is:

```
<%@include file="../include/include.jsp"%>
<%@include file="../decorators/tbs_imports.jsp"%>
<html>
<head>
<title><s:message code="title"></s:message></title>
<style>
html,body {
background-color: #eee;
}

body {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.content {
    width: 300px;
}

/* The white background content wrapper */
.container>.content {
    background-color: rgba(113, 121, 225, .15);
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 -20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.login-form {
    margin-left: 70px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.login.j_username.focus();
}

function changeFlag() {
    var lang = $("#langDrop option:selected").text();

    if (lang == 'Portugues') {
        $('#flag').attr('src', '../images/br.png');

    }

    if (lang == 'English') {
        $('#flag').attr('src', '../images/en.png');
    }

    if (lang == 'Espanol') {
        $('#flag').attr('src', '../images/es.png');
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"
    class="container">

    <div style="padding-bottom: 5px">
        <img
            style="padding-top: 10px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"
            src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/logo_pims_scf_grande.png" />
    </div>


    <c:if test="${not empty duplicated_user}">
        <div
            style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center"
            class="content alert alert-error">
            <strong><s:message code="login-duplicate-user" /></strong>
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <br /> <br />

    <c:if test="${not empty session}">
        <div
            style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center"
            class="content alert alert-error">
            <strong><s:message code="session-maxLimitReached" /></strong>
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${not empty corrupted}">
        <div
            style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center"
            class="content alert alert-error">
            <strong><s:message
                    code="session-value-corrupted-in-the-database" /></strong>
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${empty session}">
        <c:if test="${empty corrupted}">
            <div style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"
                class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="login-form">
                        <h4 style="padding-bottom: 10px">Login</h4>
                        <form id="j_acegi_security_check" onsubmit="return true;"
                            name="login"
                            action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_acegi_security_check"
                            method="POST">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <input style="height: 25px;" id="username" name="j_username"
                                        type="text" placeholder="Username">
                                </div>

                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <input style="height: 25px;" name="j_password" id="password"
                                        type="password" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>

                                <br>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                                    <s:message code="join" />
                                </button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </c:if>
    </c:if>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The WebContent folder structure is:

```
WebContent
- css
- images
- js
- META-INF
- WEB-INF
    - classes
    - jsp
    - lib
    - tags
    - index.jsp
    - web.xml
```

Since this application is annotations driven, the web.xml file is blank. And index.jsp redirects to /jsp/user/login.jsp.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your failed attempt too (JSP, static content)

Comment: jsp added. Static contents are images, js and css. Not much sense posting them here, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make more specific urlPattern override broader pattern with annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813201/how-to-make-more-specific-urlpattern-override-broader-pattern-with-annotations)